# Proving a number can be chosen to a multiply a $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function so that it never exceeds another function

Tags: inequality

Let $p,q,r$ be real numbers with $p,r,pr-q^2 > 0$. I am trying to prove $\exists\gamma> 0$ s.t. $\forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 . px^2 + 2qxy + ry^2 \geq \gamma(x^2+y^2).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left-hand side is nearly square: it's related to $(\sqrt{p} x + \sqrt{r} y)^2$. Manipulate that into exactly the right form: $p x^2 + 2q x y+ r y^2 = 2 x y \left(q-\sqrt{p r}\right)+\left(\sqrt{p} x+\sqrt{r} y\right)^2$. Now you can use the conditions to bound the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

The term on the left-hand side can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p & q \\ q & r\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$. The assumptions yield that the matrix in the middle is positive semidefinite. Now observe that if $\gamma$ is between 0 and the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix, the modified matrix $\begin{pmatrix} p - \gamma & q \\ q & r - \gamma\end{pmatrix}$ is still positive definite.